# strtol in Glibc's implement confused

Tags: c, glibc

Recently I'm reading the Glibc(2.16) source code on its newest release. While on the `strtol`, I got the following code

```
/* some other code ... */
while (*nptr >= '0' && *nptr <= '9') {
    unsigned long int digval = *nptr - '0';
        if (result > LONG_MAX / 10 ||
            (sign > 0 ? result == LONG_MAX / 10 && digval > LONG_MAX % 10
                : (result == ((unsigned long int) LONG_MAX + 1) / 10 &&
                      digval > ((unsigned long int) LONG_MAX + 1) % 10))) {
                        errno = ERANGE;
                        return sign > 0 ? LONG_MAX : LONG_MIN;
                }
                result *= base;
                result += digval;
                ++nptr;
}
```

The code to judge the `ERANGE` error may seems hard to read, To make it more clearly, I recode it like that

```
unsigned long int 
is_overflow(unsigned long int result, int sign, int digval) {
    if (result > LONG_MAX / 10) {
        goto error;
    }

    if (sign > 0) {
        if (result == LONG_MAX / 10 && digval > LONG_MAX % 10)
            goto error:
    } else {
        if (result == ((unsigned long int) LONG_MAX + 1) / 10 &&
                    digval > ((unsigned long int) LONG_MAX + 1) % 10)
                    goto error;
    }

error: 
    errno = ERANGE;
    return sign > 0 ? LONG_MAX : LONG_MIN;
}
```

And I write some code to test the long-if-statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LONG_MAX 2147483647L
int main() {
        int sign = 0;
        int expr_val = 0;
        int digval = '2';

        /* without any modification */
        expr_val = LONG_MAX / 10 && digval > LONG_MAX % 10;
        printf("%d\n", expr_val);

        expr_val = (unsigned long int) LONG_MAX + 1) / 10 &&
                digval > ((unsigned long int) LONG_MAX + 1) % 10;
        printf("%d\n", expr_val);

        return 0;
}
```

These glibc origin code seems like to judge whether `result` equal to `true`, because the `expr_val` alway equal to be `true`.

My question is why the code add such a test for `result`, is

```
result > LONG_MAX / 10
```

sufficient to judge the successive overflow? And no matter `result == 1` or `result == 0` it  always to be a valid digital value, why author do this?

Comment: Your `is_overflow()` function needs to have `sign` (and `base`) passed to it.  The digit detection needs to account for bases greater than 10 (the specification of `strtol()` allows up to base 36).  The calculation is hardwired for decimal but needs to be rewired to deal with non-decimal bases.  Your `is_overflow()` function only ever goes through the error return code; there is no non-error return in it.

Comment: Yes, from compiler point of view, it is, but it's just a more clear edition, not a firm function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (result == LONG_MAX / 10 && digval > LONG_MAX % 10)
```

means

```
if ((result == LONG_MAX / 10) && (digval > LONG_MAX % 10))
```

and not

```
if (result == (LONG_MAX / 10 && digval > LONG_MAX % 10))
```

And the `result > LONG_MAX / 10` check alone is not enough because e.g. with your `LONG_MAX` value, if `result` is `214748364`, then we also need to check `digval`, because `1` will not overflow, but `9` would.

Comment: And further, if the sign is going to be negative, then the maximum we can go up to is actually one more (thus all the `LONG_MAX + 1`s in the `sign <= 0` case.

Comment: So...we should use parentheses without any assumption.. Great answer!